# c++ websocket frame send causes server to close the connection

Tags: c++, websocket

I'm having some issues making a websocket client/server in c++ . I'm learning from the poco source code and the protocol refernces from here :
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.3

I could have used poco websockets but I want to build an async websockets built on my async socket implementation

all my code is written for windows only and I'm testing with chrome debugging protocol found here : https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot

I firstly connect to the server using this function :

```
bool LIB_NAMESPACE::net::WebSocket::Connect(string_view Host, uint16_t Port, string_view Path, string_view Origin)
{
    Dns dns;
    if (!dns.Resolve(Host))
        return false;
    
    SockAddr *AddrPtr;

    for (auto& Addr : dns.AddrsInfo) // std::variant<IpV4Addr, IpV6Addr>
    {
        if (Addr.Addrs.index() == 0)
            AddrPtr = static_cast<SockAddr*>(&std::get<0>(Addr.Addrs));
        else if (Addr.Addrs.index() == 1)
            AddrPtr = static_cast<SockAddr*>(&std::get<1>(Addr.Addrs));
        else
            continue;
        AddrPtr->port = Port;
        if (Connect(*AddrPtr, Path, Host, Origin))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool LIB_NAMESPACE::net::WebSocket::Connect(const SockAddr & addr, string_view Path, string_view host, string_view Origin)
{
    sock.Close();

    Socket ConnectorSock{ addr.Family(), SocketType::TcpStream, ProtocolType::Tcp };
    if (!ConnectorSock)
        return false;

    if (!ConnectorSock.Connect(addr))
        return false;


    std::string RequesBuffer =
        "GET " + static_cast<std::string>(Path) + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    RequesBuffer += "Host: " + (!host.empty() ? static_cast<std::string>(host) : addr.IpStr());
    if (addr.port == 80)
        RequesBuffer += "\r\n";
    else
        RequesBuffer += ':' + std::to_string(addr.port) + "\r\n";
    RequesBuffer +=
        "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
        "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
        "Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==\r\n"
        "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r\n";

    auto Sent = ConnectorSock.Send(RequesBuffer.c_str(), RequesBuffer.size());
    if (Sent <= 0 || Sent != RequesBuffer.size())
        return false;

    string Response;
    char chunk[100];
    while (!Response.ends_with("\r\n\r\n"))
    {
        auto Recved = ConnectorSock.Recv(chunk, 100);
        if (Recved <= 0)
            return false;
        Response.append(chunk, chunk + Recved);
    }

    std::cout << Response << std::endl;
    /*
    HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
    Upgrade: WebSocket
    Connection: Upgrade
    Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
    */

    // needs better http parsing

    if (!Response.icontains("HTTP/1.1 101") || !Response.icontains("Upgrade: websocket")
        || !Response.icontains("Connection: Upgrade") || !Response.icontains("Sec-WebSocket-Accept"))
        return false;

    sock = std::move(ConnectorSock);
    return true;
}
```

the connection gets opened, however I'm missing the validating the Sec-WebSocket-Accept but I think this is fine for now and may be implemented later

then I declare these structs to send data to the server :

```
class big_endian_u16
{
        uint16_t big_endian_val;
    public:

        big_endian_u16() : big_endian_val(0) {}
        
        big_endian_u16(uint16_t val) : big_endian_val(_byteswap_ushort(val)) {}

        operator uint16_t() const { return _byteswap_ushort(big_endian_val); }

};

class big_endian_u32
{
        uint32_t big_endian_val;
    public:

        big_endian_u32() : big_endian_val(0) {}

        big_endian_u32(uint32_t val) : big_endian_val(_byteswap_ulong(val)) {}

        operator uint32_t() const { return _byteswap_ulong(big_endian_val); }

};

class big_endian_u64
{
        uint64_t big_endian_val;
    public:

        big_endian_u64() : big_endian_val(0) {}

        big_endian_u64(uint64_t val) : big_endian_val(_byteswap_uint64(val)) {}

        operator uint64_t() const { return _byteswap_uint64(big_endian_val); }

};

struct WebSocketHeaderRaw
{
        bool FinalFragment : 1;
        char RSV1 : 1;
        char RSV2 : 1;
        char RSV3 : 1;
        WebSocketFrame OpCode : 4;
        bool IsMasked : 1;
        unsigned char PayloadLength : 7;

        WebSocketHeaderRaw()
        {
        static_assert(sizeof(WebSocketHeaderRaw) == 2, "invalid size of WebSocketHeaderRaw");
        }

};

enum class WebSocketFrame : unsigned char
{
   Continuation = 0X0,
   Text= 0x1,
   Binary = 0x2,
   Close = 0x8,
   Ping = 0x9,
   Pong = 0xA,
};

constexpr int MaxPayloadSize = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();

inline void MaskUnmask(char *Buffer, const char *UnMaskedBuffer, int Length, 
char Mask[4])
{
   for (auto i : range(0, Length))
       Buffer[i] = UnMaskedBuffer[i] ^ Mask[i % 4];
}
```

and this is the send method :

```
int LIB_NAMESPACE::net::WebSocket::SendFrame(WebSocketFrame FrameType, const char * Buffer, int Length)
{
    WebSocketHeaderRaw RawHeader;
    RawHeader.FinalFragment = true;
    RawHeader.RSV1 = 0;
    RawHeader.RSV2 = 0;
    RawHeader.RSV3 = 0;
    RawHeader.IsMasked = MustMask; // this is true because I'm using the websocket as client
    RawHeader.OpCode = FrameType; // I send only text frames -> 0x1
    big_endian_u16 u16Length;
    big_endian_u64 u64Length;
    char Mask[4];
    
    uint32_t u32Length = static_cast<uint32_t>(Length);

    if (u32Length < 126)
        RawHeader.PayloadLength = static_cast<unsigned char>(u32Length);
    
    else if (u32Length < std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max())
    {
        RawHeader.PayloadLength = 126;
        u16Length = static_cast<uint16_t>(u32Length);
    }
    else
    {
        RawHeader.PayloadLength = 127;
        u64Length = static_cast<uint64_t>(u32Length);
    }

    std::vector<char> MaskedBuffer;
    if (MustMask)
    {
        *(uint32_t*)Mask = RandomULongLong(std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max(), std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max() - 1); // uses c++ random library
        MaskedBuffer.resize(Length);
        MaskUnmask(MaskedBuffer.data(), Buffer, Length, Mask);
        Buffer = MaskedBuffer.data();
    }

    int Sent = sock.Send((char*)&RawHeader, sizeof(RawHeader));
    if (Sent <= 0)
        return Sent;
    
    if (u16Length)
    {
        Sent = sock.Send((char*)&u16Length, sizeof(u16Length));
        if (Sent <= 0)
            return Sent;
    }

    else if (u64Length)
    {
        Sent = sock.Send((char*)&u16Length, sizeof(u64Length));
        if (Sent <= 0)
            return Sent;
    }

    if (MustMask)
    {
        Sent = sock.Send(Mask, sizeof(Mask));
        if (Sent <= 0)
            return Sent;
    }

    return sock.Send(Buffer, Length);
}
```

after I send anything to the server it closes the connection and when I start receiving `recv` returns 0 because the server closed the connection

the receiving operation fails very early when trying to receive the headers

```
LIB_NAMESPACE::net::WebSocketHeader LIB_NAMESPACE::net::WebSocket::RecvHeader()
{
    WebSocketHeaderRaw RawHeader;
    WebSocketHeader header{ 0 };
    
    int Recved = sock.RecvAll((char*)&RawHeader, sizeof(RawHeader));
    
    if (Recved <= 0) // --> it fails here
    {
        std::cout << "[!] RecvAll (header) failed with error " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        return header;
    }

    char LengthBuffer[sizeof(uint64_t)];

    if (RawHeader.PayloadLength == 127)
    {
        Recved = sock.RecvAll(LengthBuffer, sizeof(uint64_t));
        if (Recved <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "[!] RecvAll (length 127) failed with error " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            return header;
        }
        uint64_t Length = _byteswap_uint64(*(uint64_t*)LengthBuffer);
        if (Length < MaxPayloadSize)
            header.PayloadLength = static_cast<int>(Length);
    }

    else if (RawHeader.PayloadLength == 126)
    {
        Recved = sock.RecvAll(LengthBuffer, sizeof(uint16_t));
        if (Recved <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "[!] RecvAll (length 126) failed with error " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            return header;
        }
        uint16_t Length = _byteswap_ushort(*(uint16_t*)LengthBuffer);
        if (Length < MaxPayloadSize)
            header.PayloadLength = static_cast<int>(Length);
    }

    else if (RawHeader.PayloadLength < MaxPayloadSize)
        header.PayloadLength = static_cast<int>(RawHeader.PayloadLength);

    if (!header.PayloadLength)
    {
        std::cout << "[!] PayloadLength is 0 " << std::endl;
        return header;
    }

    if (RawHeader.IsMasked)
    {
        Recved = sock.RecvAll(header.MaskKey, sizeof(header.MaskKey));
        if (Recved <= 0)
        {
            std::cout << "[!] RecvAll (Mask) failed with error " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
            header.PayloadLength = 0;
            return header;
        }
    }

    header.FinalFragment = RawHeader.FinalFragment;
    header.IsMasked = RawHeader.IsMasked;
    header.OpCode = RawHeader.OpCode;
    header.extensions.RSV1 = RawHeader.RSV1;
    header.extensions.RSV2 = RawHeader.RSV2;
    header.extensions.RSV3 = RawHeader.RSV3;

    return header;

}
```

this is my usage :

```
int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{

    std::string wsPath; // chrome path of webSocketDebuggerUrl
    cout << "enter the path : ";
    cin >> wsPath;
    rad::net::WebSocket ws;
    if (!ws.Connect("localhost", 9222, std::string_view(wsPath)))
        cout << "[!] failed to connect" << endl;
    else
        cout << "[*] connected successfully" << endl;
    if (ws.SendTextFrame(R"({"id": 1, "method": "Network.enable" })") <= 0) // this passes but the server closes the connection
    {
        cout << "[!] failed to send the frame !" << endl;
        getchar();
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        std::vector<char> Buffer;
        if (ws.RecvTextFrame(Buffer) <= 0) // always fails here
            break;
        std::cout << ">> " << string_view(Buffer.data(), Buffer.size()) << std::endl;
    }
    cout << "[!] failed to receive the frame !" << endl;
    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

any help is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit fields were ordered in memory from low to high but the bits in the header packet were ordered from high to low

This order of bit fields is guaranteed in msvc according to this reference :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/cpp-bit-fields?view=vs-2019

I tried with gcc and it seems to have the same behaviour

So I had to reverse each byte components in the struct to receive the correct result

I also tried setting  and extracting the bits with bitwise operators and it worked as well bit fields but bit fields is more elegant for me